# Are .kar Apache Karaf files meant to expose features only?

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, karaf

I am very new to OSGi and Karaf and I am still getting my head around the concepts and architecture.

My question is related to the .kar files which are created with the karaf-maven-plugin.

Does a .kar file meant to only install features into a Karaf runtime? What if we create a bundle and rename it to .kar instead of .jar. Is this a valid use case for .kar files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a [`kar`](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/kar) file is much more than that as it is a mechanism to provide not only the `features.xml` but also any related OSGi bundles, configuration files, aso. inside a single artifact.

That's also why it contains a mandatory [`repository/`](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/kar/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/kar/internal/Kar.java#L120) directory (basically containing all OSGi bundles necessary for any of the features described by the `features.xml` in a Maven repository-style structure) and an optional [`resources/`](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/kar/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/kar/internal/Kar.java#L133) directory (containing all the additional resources referenced by a feature).

For a fully fledged example, you can have a look at the Apache Karaf framework archive:

- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/karaf/features/framework/

That one contains all the basic resources that make up the base for a custom Karaf installation and provide the basic set of features:

```
META-INF/
...
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
...
repository/
... OSGi bundles referenced by the features and the features.xml itself ...
resources/
resources/bin/
... scripts ...
resources/data/
...
resources/deploy/
...
resources/etc/
... configuration files ...
resources/lib/
... (non-OSGi) libraries needed (e.g. endorsed, extension, boot classpath) ...
resources/system/
... OSGi framework implementation(s) and related libraries ...
```